# Arduino Serial.readString() trouble

Tags: serial, arduino-mega, string, serial-data, print

Hello everyone I write my code and have some troubles.
When I write on in my serial monitor my buzzer condition wasn't changed.
Can you help me realize the reason. I wrote code with int type and it works with Serial.parseInt() function properly.

```
String ask="Please enter buzzer condition";
int buzzerPin=2;
String state;
void setup() {
  pinMode(buzzerPin,OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(115200);

}

void loop() {
 Serial.println(ask);
 state=Serial.readString();
 Serial.println(state);
 while(Serial.available()==0){
  
 }
 if(state=="on"){
  digitalWrite(buzzerPin,HIGH);
 }
 if(state=="off"){
  digitalWrite(buzzerPin,LOW);
}
}
```

Comment: What line ending have you selected in the Serial Monitor? And why do you wait for more data to arrive **after** you read a string from Serial?

Comment: @chrisl thank you you really help me I find my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Serial.readStringUntil('\n')` instead of `Serial.readString` if you use the Arduino IDE's serial monitor (where a `\n` is added as termination character when you press enter).
Also remove that `while(Serial.available()==0)`. It will wait as long as there are any bytes in the serial buffer and as you don't `Serial.read()` within the loop, the buffer will not be emptied. So, if anything is received while `Serial.println(state)` is called or if you send two termination characters, the program will be stuck in that loop.